# How should we update the [filter] description?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Currently, [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filter) is described thus:

> A program or routine that blocks access to data that meet a particular criterion. An example would be a "Web filter" that screens out adult websites. Do NOT use this tag for Java servlet filters. Use [servlet-filters] instead.

It appears, however, that very few questions tagged [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filter) are actually about this. Furthermore, the term "filter" has several well-established meanings that have nothing to do with it. Therefore, I think it makes a lot more sense to broaden the tag wiki than to try to remove the tag from questions relating to all sorts of other filters. I have no idea just how to phrase it, however. Any ideas?

Comment: fails at least [2 out 4 tests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/213575), I say better let it burn.